# onDestroy is missing. Auto completion doesn't help me

Tags: android, ondestroy

I would like to call **onDestroy()** at the end of my Activity.
Here is what i put :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.rootView));
    super.onDestroy();
    System.gc();
}
```

But, it is never called. Indeed, when I use auto completion, onDestroy never appear...
but onPause, onCreate, onStop .... yes

So do I miss something here ? I might be so stupid after all...

Comment: I just want to override onDestroy like other one do. But i can't... `public class rvListePois extends Activity implements LocationListener, OnClickListener`

Comment: the ondestroy() needs to be outside all functions and inside the class

Answer (score 3):

You should call `finish()`.

onDestroy is called automatically, althought you should not rely on being called.

onDestroy():

> The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Comment: I don't want to call finish(). I need to call some function to clean some things before application is finish. (and i don't know when it will); So onDestroy should help me ..

Comment: Yeah, you can clean up your stuff in onDestroy(), onStop()... but this methods cannot be called manually. The system will call them whenever its time to.

Comment: I know that, I'm just asking (independently to android system and if it will call or not onDestroy) why Eclipse doesn't prompt me onDestroy with my auto completion. I starting to ask questions ... Yes I put it on the same place as onBackPresses() or onPause() ..

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy may be not called

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving
>   data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content
>   provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually
>   implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an
>   activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things
>   around while the rest of its application is still running. **There are
>   situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting
>   process without calling this method (or any others) in it**, so it
>   should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.
>
> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation
>   of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Like I said on the comment I've juste wrote. why Eclipse doesn't prompt me onDestroy with my auto completion like onPause() onStop() ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your help.
I have now understand that onDestroy may not be called.

I don't know why, but now Eclipse prompt me the onDestroy method.
So it is called but not where i want to.